# What class library to use to be reference on UWP and ASPNETCORE apps

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, uwp

I would like to create a class library that can be used on my aspnetcore app and uwp app.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, the way I understand the image below (first image) I can create a .net core class library and have it reference to uwp and aspnetcore.

What I've done is I created, a `.NET Core Class Library`, `Aspnet Core Web App`, and `UWP`.

I tried to reference `.Net Core Class Library` on my `Aspnet Core Web App`, no errors. Now, I tried to reference `.Net Core Class Library` on my `UWP` and it showed the error below (last image).

Am I better of creating PCL instead as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028887/reference-a-class-library-from-uwp-and-asp-net-5)?

PS. Im using VS2015 Update 3

[image: model][image: solution explorer][image: error]

Comment: The tooling is not ready. Generate a NuGet package, add to custom feed and then consume it in UWP project.json.

Comment: Oh I see. Should I wait for the tooling then? Is there a tutorial for that? (The generate NuGet for the UWP to consume?)

Comment: check how urgent you want to try. Public info is that the RTM of the tooling is this fall, but that means it might be as late as November.

Comment: I see. November. Maybe I'll go for PCL. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooling is now available in Visual Studio 2017 release candidate. You can now create a .Net Standard class library from a template and use this to facilitate sharing code (e.g. model objects) between an Asp.Net Core app and a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app.

[image]

.Net Standard class library is considered the successor to the portable class library (PCL).

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. Last question, is this production ready? or should I wait a little more?

Comment: Well, Visual Studio 2017 is RC now. It seems stable enough. I can't really comment on whether it's production ready for your specific needs. That's something you or your team need to decide for yourselves.