# Cannot reference .NET Core library from UWP

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, uwp, .net-core

I have a **.NET Core library** with the following project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": { }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postcompile": [
      "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration Release",
      "xcopy bin\\Release ..\\..\\lib\\ /Y"
    ]
  }
}
```

where the postcompile script creates a **nuget package** which I added as a custom feed in VS, following [these instructions](http://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds).
This is because I want to **reference it from a Windows Universal App**, which cannot be otherwise (yet), according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225130/what-class-library-to-use-to-be-reference-on-uwp-and-aspnetcore-apps).
But when I try it, I get this message:

```
Package AEther 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0).
Package AEther 1.0.0 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
```

This is where it stops making sense to me. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181004/can-i-build-uwp-with-net-core), it should work fine for netstandard >=1.6.0, while [this official table](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) says I need to target netstandard <=1.4.0, but that doesn't change anything. More confusingly, if I downgrade **both** versions of netstandard (the dependency and the target framework) to, say, 1.5, I still get this exact same error without specifying 1.6 in any of my files.

**Update**
The UWP project.json looks like this

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

**Can someone clear up** either

1. How to reference .Net Core libraries from UWP at all or
2. What is going on in my specific case?

**ANSWER**

I solved it adding an import to the UWP app as follows:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": { import [ "netstandard1.6" ] }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe there will be an update for UWP to address that.

Comment: I'd mark that as an answer, because it solves the question... thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to upgrade Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to 5.2.1

---

**Update on July, 15**

Ok, here is my result

1. create a new UWP
2. Upgrade to 5.2.2, which comes out on July, 14
3. update project.json, import "netstandard1.6"

   `{
     "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
       "Test": "1.0.0"
     },
     "frameworks": {
       "uap10.0": {
         "imports": [
           "netstandard1.6"
         ]
       }
     },
     "runtimes": {
       "win10-arm": {},
       "win10-arm-aot": {},
       "win10-x86": {},
       "win10-x86-aot": {},
       "win10-x64": {},
       "win10-x64-aot": {}
     }
   }`
4. create a new dotnet core library
5. build the library, and generate a nuget package
6. I am able to reference the .dll file or the nuget package. And i **Do** get intelligent while typing code
7. UWP is built and deployed successfully, but once i run it, an exception is thrown
   [image]

Comment: I did that (had 5.2 before). No change.

Comment: @VolkerSchmidt Could you update your UWP project.json?

Comment: YES! Thank you! Importing netstandard does it. edit: even with uwp5.2.1 and netstandard1.6

Comment: @VolkerSchmidt did you get it running?

Comment: It works with your import. In the meantime I switched to a PCL.

Comment: The import is wrong.  You're lying about what set of API UWP supports.  It only supports netstandard1.4, by importing 1.6 you're lying to nuget and will hit a runtime failure if that library uses any API that is present in netstandard1.6 but not in 1.4.

Answer (score 7):

> This is where it stops making sense to me. According to this, it
>   should work fine for netstandard >=1.6.0, while this official table
>   says I need to target netstandard <=1.4.0, but that doesn't change
>   anything. More confusingly, if I downgrade both versions of
>   netstandard (the dependency and the target framework) to, say, 1.5, I
>   still get this exact same error without specifying 1.6 in any of my
>   files.

[Universal Windows Platform maps to netstandard1.4](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms) - neither to 1.6 nor to 1.5. Therefore, your library (called `AEther` I assume) has a higher requirement than your UWP app.

> 1. How to reference .Net Core libraries from UWP at all or

As stated in [your linked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38225130/3042204) this is not supported yet in Visual Studio.

I can only guess that it is related to the support by the CLI, which is [an open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3189). As of today, it is expected to be fixed in the version 5.3 of the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` meta-package - although it was previously expected to be fixed in 5.2.2.

> 2. What is going on in my specific case?

NuGet is telling you that your package supports only the `netstandard1.6` [target framework](https://docs.nuget.org/create/targetframeworks) but not `uap10.0`. Indeed, if you unpack your `.nupkg` you'll find your DLL under `lib\netstandard1.6`.

Since [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-pack) automatically creates the `.nuspec` from your `project.json` so you'll need to fix it with the proper framework (eg. `netstandard1.4`). It'll probably be easier compiling for different frameworks, for instance [Portable profiles compatible with .NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#portable-profiles).

Comment: As I indicated, using netstandard1.4 gives the exact same error (saying netstandard1.6 is required. Hence my confusion). If I have to specifically target uap10.0, how would I do that?

Comment: to clear this up, I was targetting netstandard1.6 because another question here on SO claimed this to be the only way.

Comment: now that I have an answer, I can confirm I DO NOT have to target netstandard1.4

Comment: You simply need to update from `netstandard1.6`to `netstandard1.4` under `frameworks`. Your NuGet package must have not been re-created or refreshed properly, try increasing the version.

Comment: No changes to the NuGet package where necessary. Increasing the version works.

Comment: After editing the `project.json` you need to recreate the `.nupkg` (`dotnet pack`) and install / update it in the UWP app, so yes, a new NuGet package is necessary. Otherwise, you are still using the `netstandard1.6` one...

Comment: the project.json I had to edit IS the UWP app, not the library. And yes, I am still using netstandard1.6, and it works. I am as confused as you because it contradicts the docs, but I'm not complaining.

Comment: I was referring to my solution targeting `netstandard1.4`. I think that using `imports` might lead to runtime exceptions due to API incompatibilities, althought they may be corner cases.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. But as I said twice, targetting netstandard1.4 did not resolve the error, so sorry, that's not the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117397/discussion-between-jnovo-and-volker-schmidt).

Comment: Agree with @jnovo here.  Likely something was missing in your change to ns1.4.  You have to be very careful when making changes to a nuget package: nuget will cache the package in both the packages folder and temp.  Either change the name or blow-away those caches (nuget.exe locals is a good hammer).

Comment: When we will be able to reference Net standard 1.6 DLL inside UWP?